# Rest API counts attachments for a list item but "delete" only deletes the first attachment

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have this rest api that looks for all of the attachments for a specific item.  If it finds three attachments, for some reason the DELETE method only deletes the first one that it finds.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I want it find all three and delete all three. Not sure why it's not deleting all the attachments.

```
function findAttachmentNames(parentitem,acctname,acctnum){
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('New%20Account%20Requests')/items(" + parentitem + ")/AttachmentFiles";
console.log("line 136: "+url);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers:
        // standard header stuff that must be here
        {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    })
.done(function(data){
    var attachresult = data.d.results;
    if(attachresult.length >= 1) {
        console.log("line 154 attachresult.length: "+attachresult.length);
        for(i = 0; i<attachresult.length; i++)
        {
            filename = data.d.results[i].FileName;
            for(i=0;i<filename.length; i++){
            logHistory(filename, acctname, acctnum, parentitem);
            console.log("line 155: "+filename);
            return $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('New%20Account%20Requests')/getItembyID("+parentitem+")/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName('"+filename+"')",
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "contentType":"application/json;odata=verbose",
                'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                'X-HTTP-Method': 'DELETE',
            }
                
            })
            
            }
        }
    }
    })
.fail(function(error){
    if(attachresult.length == 0){
        console.log("Line 167: Oops. No attachment files.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  The delete method only deletes one thing at a time.  So, I took that part of the findAttachmentNames function and put it in it's own little funciton:

```
function deleteAttachments(filename){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('New%20Account%20Requests')/getItembyID("+parentitem+")/AttachmentFiles/getByFileName('"+filename+"')",
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "contentType":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            'X-HTTP-Method': 'DELETE',
        }
    })
}
```

And then I just called that function from inside the .done.  So now the .done looks like this:

```
.done(function(data){
    var attachresult = data.d.results;
    console.log("line 148: "+JSON.stringify(data.d.results));
    if(attachresult.length >= 1) {
        console.log("line 154 attachresult.length: "+attachresult.length);
        for(i = 0; i<attachresult.length; i++)
        {
            filename = data.d.results[i].FileName;
            deleteAttachments(filename);
            logHistory(filename, acctname, acctnum, parentitem);            
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately, while the code in the answer works, it is not picking up the last attachment.  So for example, if an item has 10 attachments, it deletes the first 9, updates the history log with all 10, but leaves the 10th attachment on the list item.  Any ideas???